# how to parse multiple json objects to one json object and make a pandas dataframe "keys" as columns and "values" as rows in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, key-value

How to convert multiple json objects to one json object and make a dataframe like keys as columns and values as rows in python.help would be greately appreciated
*my json doesnt have comma's after each json object*

```
data = {"name":"john",
        "class":"fifth"}
       {"name":"emma",
        "class":"sixth"}
```

#my full method
     from flask import  Flask, jsonify, request
    import cx_Oracle

```
 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.debug = True

 conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='',password='',dsn=dsn_tns)
 c.execute('''SELECT APPLE, BANANA, CARROT FROM VEGETABLES''')
 for row in c:
 data = (json.dumps(row, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str) 
 print (data)
 data = {"name":"john",
    "class":"fifth"}
   {"name":"emma",
    "class":"sixth"}
```

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON. Maybe it's NDJSON?

Comment: yes I know its not a valid json. how do i convert it to valid json and make  a dataframe out of it to keys as columns and values as rows @charlesLandau

Comment: Is every object guaranteed to have exactly two keys `name` and `class`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's invalid JSON, but I'm confident that it's invalid Python. I'm thinking that it looks like NDJSON?

If your data is in a file, and if every object is guaranteed to have exactly two keys name and class:

```
import json
import pandas a pd

data = {'name':[], 'class':[]}
with open("file.ndjson", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
       d = json.loads(line)
       data['name'].append(d['name'])
       data['class'].append(d['class'])
```

edit: You said your data are a response. This usually works for me:

```
r = # Response
pd.DataFrame(r.json())
```

Comment: it is not in a file. it is a response from a http request. can you make it dynamic rather then hard coding the colum names by using pandas.@charlesLanda and it is not in file it is just a response.every object is  guranteed name and class but all the keys should  be coulms and values should be rows dynamically

Comment: Response from what? python `requests`? `flask`?

Comment: @ritikariti I edited my answer with my first crack at doing it from a response?

Comment: i am getting an error saying that string object has no attribute "json"

Comment: @ritikariti your method of getting the request may not implement that method... but you haven't said how you got it

Comment: method is like this from flask import  Flask, jsonify, request
    import cx_Oracle

    app = Flask(__name__)
   app.debug = True

    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='',password='',dsn=dsn_tns)
    c.execute('''SELECT APPLE, BANANA, CARROT FROM VEGETABLES''')
    for row in c:
    OUTPUT = (json.dumps(row, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)

Comment: I am adding it in my question the whole method @charlrs Landau

Comment: i have the full method in the question.  can you please help me out